# Change textView color in RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: android

I want to change the color of a textView in the onBindViewHolder in the Adapter depending on a variable of data. I've tried this

```
if (survey.getAnonymous() == 0) {
    holder.surveyIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_x);
    holder.surveyAnonymous.setTextColor(R.color.red);
} else {
    holder.surveyIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check);
    holder.surveyAnonymous.setTextColor(R.color.green);
}
```

`R.color.red` is underlined in red and says

> Should use getResources().getColor(R.color.red)

I tried that and it also gives me an error.
I have tried these:

```
holder.surveyAnonymous.setTextColor(R.color.red);
holder.surveyAnonymous.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
holder.surveyAnonymous.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.red));
holder.surveyAnonymous.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(R.color.red);
```

None of these have worked and are always underlined in red, what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I ended up doing this `holder.surveyAnonymous.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(v.getContext(), R.color.red));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> int [getColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat#getcolor) (Context context, 
>                   int id)

```
 holder.surveyAnonymous.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(contextObject,(R.color.red)));
```

**FYI**

**`Color.parseColor`** - Parse the color string, and return the corresponding color-int.

```
holder.surveyAnonymous.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#54D66A");
```